# How to draw a line in Python Mayavi?

Tags: python, plot, line, draw, mayavi

How to draw a line in 3D space in Python Mayavi? Is there a function from MLAB module that allows me to specify the start and end point of the line which will be drawn?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the documentation for mayavi; 3d plotting is in the tutorials and documented [here](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#mayavi.mlab.plot3d).
It's part of `mlab`, `mayavi.mlab.plot3d(*args, **kwargs)`.

The syntax is

```
plot3d(x, y, z, ...)
```

Answer (score 6):

One important feature you can use when drawing lines is to represent them as a tube. The following example I used to draw the X, Y, Z axis along with the 3D figure (note that in my case the dimensions are big, so that you might want to adjust them):

```
import mayavi.mlab as mlab

black = (0,0,0)
white = (1,1,1)
mlab.figure(bgcolor=white)
mlab.plot3d([0, 1000], [0, 0], [0, 0], color=black, tube_radius=10.)
mlab.plot3d([0, 0], [0, 1500], [0, 0], color=black, tube_radius=10.)
mlab.plot3d([0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1500], color=black, tube_radius=10.)
mlab.text3d(1050, -50, +50, 'X', color=black, scale=100.)
mlab.text3d(0, 1550, +50, 'Y', color=black, scale=100.)
mlab.text3d(0, -50, 1550, 'Z', color=black, scale=100.)
```